# How to set environment variable in mac osx yosemite and use in PHP web application

Tags: php, environment-variables, osx-yosemite

I am creating PHP web application. I need to get environment variable in my web application. I am using Yosemite OSX.

I have executed following command:

```
launchctl setenv ENVIRONMENT development
```

I am able to get o/p for the following command:

```
launchctl getenv ENVIRONMENT 
development
```

However, when I execute following in my PHP file

```
$env = getenv('ENVIRONMENT');
echo $env;
```

I am not able to see the result "development".

For setting environment variable I have also tried following:
http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2015-04-14/mac/os-x-1010-yosemite-and-environment-variables

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite

I have also executed following command:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist
launchctl start ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist
```

When I execute `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist` it gives me

```
Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist: Operation already in progress
```

Also restart MAMP server, restart macbook. Did this for few times. But no success.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

If someone can tell me necessary steps to achieve final goal which is to use environment variable in my PHP application, I would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored the $_ENV variable?  This may have the information you need.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

Comment: I am also not able to get environment variable using $_ENV variable